# Undefined variable "file" in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error, fso

I have this VBScript code that's supposed to write to every file in a directory:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim dir: dir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".") & "/important/"

For Each file In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
    If UCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file.Name)) = "JS" Or UCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file.Name)) = "VBS" Then
        Dim op: Set op = file.OpenAsTextStream(2,-2)
        op.Write "This file has been written!"
        op.Close
    End If
Next

MsgBox("Done!")
```

But the Windows Script Host keeps complaining and telling me that I have an undefined variable named "file". The error occurs on line 7. I have no idea why this error is occuring and help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`Option Explicit` means *All variables must be declared before use*.

The `file` variable is not declared, do so by adding:

```
Dim file
```

To your code along with the other `Dim`s.